# Implement unlimited frequency in rating-widget.com

Tags: javascript, rating-system

The [rating-widget documentation](http://rating-widget.com/documentation/) writes about unlimited user rating frequency of their star rating system. But I'm not sure how to add it to the main function code.

Where can I add the line `frequency=unlimited`. Should be easy. But I'm a JS rookie.

```
(function(d, t, e, m){
    window.RW_Async_Init = function(){
        RW.init({
            huid: "336233",
            uid: "2e7de74f3aeb426c10a2087ead09259c",
            source: "website",
            options: {
                "size": "medium",
                "style": "oxygen",
                "isDummy": false
            } 
        });
        RW.render();
    };
    // Append Rating-Widget JavaScript library.
    var rw, s = d.getElementsByTagName(e)[0], id = "rw-js",
        l = d.location, 
        ck = "Y" + t.getFullYear() + "M" + t.getMonth() + "D" + t.getDate(),
        p = l.protocol,
        f = ((l.search.indexOf("DBG=") > -1) ? "" : ".min"),
        a = ("https:" == p ? "secure." + m + "js/" : "js." + m);
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;              
    rw = d.createElement(e);
    rw.id = id; rw.async = true;
    rw.type = "text/javascript";
    rw.src = p + "//" + a + "external" + f + ".js?ck=" + ck;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(rw, s);
}(document, new Date(), "script", "rating-widget.com/"));
```

Comment: I hope you obfuscated your id in there, as you don't want readers to use your account...

Comment: yes...thats a new generated id...copied direclty from the site...can you help ? :)

Comment: im sure you can...please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [options object section](http://rating-widget.com/documentation/#rw-options-object) it describes which options you can specify, which includes `frequency`, so you could specify this key/value:

```
frequency: RW.FREQUENCY.UNLIMITED
```

You would specify that in the `init` call, in the `options` object, like this:

```
RW.init({
    huid: "336233",
    uid: "2e7de74f3aeb426c10a2087ead09259c",
    source: "website",
    options: {
        frequency: RW.FREQUENCY.UNLIMITED, // <-- added
        "size": "medium",
        "style": "oxygen",
        "isDummy": false
    } 
});
```

NB: The documentation is not really complete, as the above syntax is not covered in the [RW methods section](http://rating-widget.com/documentation/#rw-methods), where the `init` call is said to need the `uid` as the first argument. This evidently is only one of the ways to call `init`, as the [page you used](http://rating-widget.com/get/rating/) to grab your code passes a nested object as the first (and only) argument.

Also, it seems more inline with the main documentation to use the predefined enumerations for setting the options. So you would set the `size` with `RW.SIZE.SMALL` instead of `"small"`.

Comment: Thank you once again :))